# Align the letterhead on top of PDF document using iTextSharp in C#

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I have the following code

```
Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 25, 25, 25, 10);
string pathfile = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Temp_SaveLocation"];
string fileName = "SomeName.pdf";
path = pathfile + fileName;
PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create));
pdfDoc.Open();

Image imghead = Image.GetInstance(templateFolder + "Letterhead.png");

pdfDoc.Add(imghead);
pdfWriter.CloseStream = true;
pdfDoc.Close();
```

I am trying to properly align the letterhead on top of the PDF document so that it will look nice and fit properly

I tried imghead.ScaleAbsoluteWidth(pdfDoc.PageSize.Width); but still the letterhead appears cut off. I also tried setting the Width property, but there no aspect ratio, and because of that the letterhead looks odd

Is there any specific way to fit the letterhead properly on top of the PDF?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: having never used this i cant really help but if imghead.ScaleAbsoluteWidth() exists im sure this function is there as well: imghead.ScaleAbsoluteHeigtht()

Comment: I have to provide values for these functions. Every value I tried keeps the letterhead distorted

Comment: You add that image using `Document.Add`. Thus, you make it subject to the iText layout engine which works in the inner page area (excluding margins) only. Thus, an image with width `pdfDoc.PageSize.Width` cannot fit. Also, as you have set the top margin to 25, something added using `Document.Add` will not be at the top.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Is the anything in the code that can keep the aspect ratio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer I was looking for

```
imghead.ScaleToFit(150f, 150f);
```